# Ball stop when animation is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have basic idea in mind, A ball is bouncing and after all bounces it should stop at stage animation completes.

**Problem-**

Ball bounces are good and animation is what i wanted it to be. But still it is not stopping when animation completes, it goes Down out of frame.

A solution i am not compatible with-

```
if(y>=300)
{
x=110;
y=300;
}
```

But ball is vibrating.

**I want-**

Ball should stop smoothly.

**Fiddle link**-  http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/xWvEU/

Comment: Ball should stop smoothly after what? when pressing a button?

Comment: @ClydeFrog no when value of x,y directions are respected lowest and highest, function is being called on body onload.

Comment: Animation should stop moving after it completes.

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't match your problem. The ball is bouncing around the box. What says the animation is complete? You will need to retain a reference to the id returned by setTimeout and use clearTimeout to stop the draw method.

Comment: @DaveAnderson  Ball goes out of frame, i want stop ball instead of going out of canvas frame

Comment: In the fiddle ball keeps bouncing forever, doesn't go out of frame

Comment: Please see fiddle now, my mistake, did some edits and updated.

Comment: @mornaner , go fiddle now.

Comment: try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/KUez8/ - adjusted braces, dampening, and made sure that ball never goes out of frame

Comment: @Sebastian if you change the `y` max value to 290 will see the whole ball

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [clear the interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval) where you draw your animation.

On your code I did this changes:

```
function init()
{
  var ctx=document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

  return interval = setInterval(draw,10);
}
```

And then on the if:

```
if(y>=300)
{
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Check it on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eNQs5/1/)